# Drupal 7 Form Api AJAX callback on a text_format field do not work

Tags: ajax, forms, api, drupal, field

I have a field in my custom module

```
$form['update']['text'] = array(
    //'#type' => 'textarea',
    '#type' => 'text_format',
```

If I use textarea everything is ok, but if I use the text_format my ajax callback do not change the value of the field.

```
function maintenance_update_form_update_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $entry = $form_state['entries'][$form_state['values']['aid']];
  // Setting the #value of items is the only way I was able to figure out
  // to get replaced defaults on these items. #default_value will not do it
  // and shouldn't.

  dpm($form_state['entries'][$form_state['values']['aid']]);

  foreach (array('status', 'type', 'title', 'text', 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'notes') as $item) {
    $form['update'][$item]['#value'] = $entry->$item;
    //dpm($entry);
    //drupal_set_message("entry->item értéke: ENTRY: $entry, ITEM: $item , $entry->$item");
  }
```

What can be wrong with this field? As far as I know this type also support ajax requests....

```
  //drupal_set_message('Callback $form');
  dpm($form);
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple - **text_format** is not simple single-value form item. It takes array for **value** param like that

```
array(
 'value' => '123123',
 'format' => 'html'
)
```

So, if you want to change value try this code:

```
$form['update']['text']['value']['#value'] = 'text message';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ProFak! You are the best:-) I was inattentive. It works now.

Comment: I'm using the same text_format for my form field, but the value entered by the user in the field is not reflected in the formstate. $form['update']['value'] is empty. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ProFak solution, if you want to change the **format** of the text_format field type, you will have to use the following code

```
$altered_text_format = 'full_html';

$form['update']['format']['format']['#value'] = $altered_text_format;
```

So the complete solutions will look like as below

```
function maintenance_update_form_update_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $entry = $form_state['entries'][$form_state['values']['aid']];
  // Setting the #value of items is the only way I was able to figure out
  // to get replaced defaults on these items. #default_value will not do it
  // and shouldn't.

  foreach (array('status', 'type', 'title', 'text', 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'notes') as $item) {
        // @ProFak Solution
        $form['update']['text']['value']['#value'] = $entry->$item;
        // @Sukhjinder Singh additional solution
        $altered_text_format = 'full_html';
        $form['update']['format']['format']['#value'] = $altered_text_format;
 }

 return $form['update'];
}
```